# Connection reset after partial page load on .net site

Tags: .net, connection, reset

We are trying to move a MS SQL vb.net website from one server to another. It works perfectly on the initial server but on the new server, most pages are fine but the home page, which has quite a lot of data using a number of sqldatasources with gridviews, repeaters and an update panel loads two of the three columns but doesn't finish loading, eventually timing out with a connection was reset error message from the browser.
We've tried removing the 3rd column but still get the issue, we've tried removing an update panel from the 2nd column and still get the issue. We have a version working with most stripped out but cannot really identify the problem and because this is working on the original server, and because the other page are working, don't really know what to do next. Tried using fiddler and SQL profiler to understand the problem but don't see anything.

Any suggestions on the approach to troubleshoot greatfully rec'd.

Comment: Could you please edit your question so it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the HTTP server timing out as it is taking too long to render the page.  Try to create a temporary "test" page and replace the database content with mocked up content (i.e. faking the DB calls) there is probably something on that page that is taking way too much to load.  If this renders fine on initial server, think about the location of the new server, is it doing certain network hops to get to the database?  Is it slower to access the database than the original server?  This is what I would look into from what you describe above.